# Remove values from numpy array closer to each other

Tags: python, numpy

Actually i want to remove the elements from numpy array which are closer to each other.For example i have array `[1,2,10,11,18,19]` then I need code that can give output like `[1,10,18]` because `2` is closer to 1 and so on.

Comment: What do you mean when you say `2 is closer to 1`, closer than what?

Comment: Define `Closer`, From vague definition it looks like you want to start from start of the array then if next element is difference of one then remove else keep. But better solution would be to use k-mean, because it is stat question I think, use k-mean to make groups and then choose min value from each group.

Comment: what should the absolute difference be between digits in the array? Also, specify if the rule is applicable to only adjacent array element. Additionally, should the array retain the smaller of the two numbers being compared. How do you solve cases of equal numbers ?

Answer (score 3):

In the following is provided an additional solution using numpy functionalities (more precisely  [`np.ediff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ediff1d.html?highlight=ediff1d#numpy.ediff1d) which makes the differences between consecutive elements of a given array. This code considers as threshold the value associated to the `th` variable.

```
a = np.array([1,2,10,11,18,19])
th = 1
b = np.delete(a, np.argwhere(np.ediff1d(a) <= th) + 1) # [1, 10, 18]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple function to find the first values of series of consecutives values in a 1D numpy array.

```
import numpy as np

def find_consec(a, step=1):
    vals = []
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        if i == 0:
            diff = a[i + 1] - x
            if diff == step:
                vals.append(x)
        elif i < a.size-1:
            diff = a[i + 1] - x
            if diff > step:
                vals.append(a[i + 1])
    return np.array(vals)

a = np.array([1,2,10,11,18,19])
find_consec(a) # [1, 10, 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. below is the code that can answer you question:

```
def closer(arr,cozy):
    result = []
    result.append(arr[0])
    for i in range(1,len(arr)-1):
        if arr[i]-result[-1]>cozy:
            result.append(arr[i])
    print result
```

Example:

```
a = [6,10,7,20,21,16,14,3,2]
a.sort()
closer(a,1)
output : [2, 6, 10, 14, 16, 20]
closer(a,3)
Output: [2, 6, 10, 14, 20]
```

Comment: Can you  please let me know the reason for down flag. So that i can improve my answer for future

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late to the party. But Agglomerative Clustering may be what you're looking for. By specifying the distance threshold and linkage criterion, the algorithm will return the desired result.

```py
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
a = np.array([1,2,10,11,18,19])
dups_filter = AgglomerativeClustering(linkage="single", distance_threshold=1.1, metric="manhattan", n_clusters=None)

cluster_labels = dups_filter.fit_predict(a.reshape(-1,1))
filtered_array = np.array([])
for c in range(dups_filter.n_clusters_):
 filtered_array = np.append(filtered_array, np.min(a[cluster_labels==c]))
```