# Pythonic way to remove elements from Numpy array closer than threshold

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, optimization

What is the best way to remove the minimal number of elements from a sorted Numpy array so that the minimal distance among the remaining is always bigger than a certain threshold?

For example, if the threshold is `1`, the following sequence `[0.1, 0.5, 1.1, 2.5, 3.]` will become `[0.1, 1.1, 2.5]`. The `0.5` is removed because it is too close to `0.1` but then `1.1` is preserved because it is far enough from `0.1`.

My current code:

```py
import numpy as np

MIN_DISTANCE = 1    
a = np.array([0.1, 0.5, 1.1, 2.5, 3.])

for i in range(len(a)-1):
    if(a[i+1] - a[i] < MIN_DISTANCE):
        a[i+1] = a[i]

a = np.unique(a)
```

```
a
array([0.1, 1.1, 2.5])
```

Is there a more efficient way to do so?

Note that my question is similar to [Remove values from numpy array closer to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53775302/remove-values-from-numpy-array-closer-to-each-other) but not exactly the same.

Comment: Did you try numba - https://numba.pydata.org/?

Comment: What is the application of this?  Additionally this is not distance, you are talking about difference, and it also appears you need elements sorted.

Comment: thanks @Divakar, Numba does improve execution time

Comment: My question still remains, is there a more pythonic way to write this?

Comment: I meant 2D/3D convolution supported by SciPy.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57432437/optimize-iteration-through-numpy-array-when-averaging-adjacent-values).

Comment: You can look at `np.ediff1d` and `np.split`, although the behavior may differ from yours since you are modifying the array during the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [numpy.ufunc.accumulate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) to iterate thru adjacent pairs of the array instead of the `for` loop.

- The `numpy.add.accumulate` example or [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) probably shows best what it's doing.
- Along with [numpy.frompyfunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html) your condition can be applied as `ufunc` ([universal functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) ).

---

**Code:** (with an extended array to cross check some additional cases, but works with your array as well)

```
import numpy as np


MIN_DISTANCE = 1
a = np.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 1.1, 2.5, 3., 4., 6., 6.1])
print("original: \n" + str(a))


def my_py_function(arr1, arr2):
    if(arr2 - arr1 < MIN_DISTANCE):
        arr2 = arr1
    return arr2


my_np_function = np.frompyfunc(my_py_function, 2, 1)

my_np_function.accumulate(a, dtype=np.object, out=a).astype(float)


print("complete: \n" + str(a))
a = np.unique(a)
print("unique: \n" + str(a))
```

**Result:**

```
original:
[0.1 0.5 0.6 0.7 1.1 2.5 3.  4.  6.  6.1]
complete:
[0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 1.1 2.5 2.5 4.  6.  6. ]
unique:
[0.1 1.1 2.5 4.  6. ]
```

---

Concerning execution time [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) shows a turnaround at array length of about 20.

- Your code is much faster (relative) for your array length of 5
- whereas for array length >>20 the accumulate option speeds up considerably (~35% in time for array length 300)

Comment: Very interesting solution, but is it possible to optimize this with Numba? Otherwise for very large vectors or a large amount of function call, my code optimized with Numba is still more performant.

Comment: @Giampietro Seu I haven't worked with Numba yet, therefore I can't tell how it would handle that code.