# Remove numbers in list that are within +/- 100 of any other list member in R

Tags: r

I have a list of numbers, and want to remove 'similar' entries.

Here's an example:

```
tops <- c(14500, 14441, 14551, 8600, 8650, 8730)
```

I want to remove any values that are within 100 of each other, so I'm left with:

```
result <- c(14500, 8600)
```

Approximate removal is okay, so it doesn't matter for eg if we iterate over every item in the list, but for e.g. if we ask, is list item 2 within 100 of list item 1? If so, remove, if not, treat list item number 2 as new comparator, is list item 3 within 100 of list item? If so, remove. etc. etc.

Preferable in base R or dplyr

Comment: Is there a reason you are using character strings with quotes like `"14500"` instead of numbers without quotes `14500`?

Comment: Also, 14500 is within 100 of 14551 and 14441, so why is it in the result? Do you want to keep the first number? What if you had input as `100, 150, 199, 200, 201`? Which would you want to keep? (And is the "within 100" a `<` or `<=`?)

Comment: Between 14500 and 14441, why do you choose 14500? The same question for 8600 and 8650. Which number has the priority to stay?

Comment: And, is the list sorted? If not, is it okay to sort it? That could improve efficiency a lot.

Comment: I want to almost deduplicate a list of numbers, but instead of exact matches, I want a roundabout approximations. 

What I want to know is that there is a number close to 14500, and one close to 8600. That there are also numbers at 8650 and 8730 do not matter to me. 

The list is not sorted, but can be if it makes it easier. And there is no priority currently. Perhaps it is smarter to sort high to low and then assign priority on largest number?

Comment: A possible implementation in Python https://stackoverflow.com/a/53775877/8806649

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algorithm that may work when **the vector is sorted from smallest to largest values**, but I'm not totally convinced that it works

```r
dist_max <- 100

# Sort the vector
tops_sort <- sort(tops)

# Algorithm to get the smallest values within `dist_max`
results <- tops_sort[1]
for (j in 2:length(tops_sort)){
  if (tops_sort[j] - tops_sort[j - 1] > dist_max) {
    results <- c(results, tops_sort[j])
  }
}

results
# [1]  8600 14441
```

Two shorter solutions with the `diff` function

```r
dist_max <- 100

# With base R
tops_sort <- sort(tops) # Sort the vector
results <- tops_sort[c(T, diff(tops_sort) > dist_max)]
results
# [1]  8600 14441

# With dplyr
results <- tops %>% sort %>% .[c(T, diff(.) > dist_max)] # Or vctrs::vec_slice(c(T, diff(.) > dist_max))
results
# [1]  8600 14441
```

Comment: Thank you, it's worked neatly on my current dataset, and I think at most it would require some manual tweaking of the output for edge cases.